# How can I find which key a value is associated to when the keys are all arrays of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, lodash

In my current React/Typescript project I'm looking to find out which key a value is in, when each key is an array of strings. When I know what key it is associated to, I then need to use that to change another object. Code below to try make it a bit clearer.

```
const output = {
    a: false,
    b: false,
    c: false,
}

const checkAgainst = {
    a: ["1", "2", "3"],
    b: ["4", "5", "6"],
    c: ["7", "8", "9"]
}

const checkThing = "5"

// change output based on a match here.

return output;
```

I've tried a few different solutions with looping through the checkAgainst object, but nothing seems to be able to properly identify, and then change out the value of (in this case b) to true. I'm down to use some lodash if needed (as it's already part of the project), but I haven't been able to find a solution that properly does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of `checkAgainst` object and then use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to loop over the keys and change the `output` object

```js
let output = {
  a: false,
  b: false,
  c: false,
};

const checkAgainst = {
  a: ["1", "2", "3"],
  b: ["4", "5", "6"],
  c: ["7", "8", "9"],
};

const checkThing = "5";

output = Object.keys(checkAgainst).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = checkAgainst[curr].includes(checkThing);
  return acc;
}, output);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) combined with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to set/update the `output` object `key` values:

```js
const output = {
  a: false,
  b: false,
  c: false,
}

const checkAgainst = {
  a: ["1", "2", "3"],
  b: ["4", "5", "6"],
  c: ["7", "8", "9"],
}

const checkThing = "5"

Object.entries(checkAgainst).forEach(([k, v]) => output[k] = v.includes(checkThing))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

HR01M8055 has a great answer.

I believe this could be another way to write it

`checkStore` checks the arrays of the `checkAgainst` keys for the item passed in (ex: `checkThing`), then sets the output at that same key to `true` (if match is found) or `false` (if no match is found).

```
const checkAgainst = {
    a: [1, 2, 3],
    b: [4, 5, 6],
    c: [7, 8, 9]
};

const output = {
    a: false,
    b: false,
    c: false
};

//loop through checkAgainst object via its keys to check if any of the keys contain the item
function checkStore(item) {

    for(let key in checkAgainst) {
   
        if(checkAgainst[key].includes(item)){
            output[key] = true
        } else {
            output[key] = false
        } 
    }

    return output
};


const checkThing = 5;

checkStore(checkThing); //output { a: false, b: true, c: false }

checkStore(1); //output { a: true, b: false, c: false }

checkStore(11); // output { a: false, b: false, c: false }
```